# How to calculate finite difference derivative approximation matrix for directional images?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to understand how to calculate finite difference derivative approximation matrix for directional images. By directional image, I mean an image having only one direction, for example:
[image]

The above image has only one direction so we can say that the gradient orientation for this image is a positive angle (e.g. 50 degrees). I have the following code which I have found to calculate finite difference derivative approximation matrix. I have a problem in understanding this code. Why when Th>=0 (Th is the orientation), the derivative in y-direction must be constructed using the forward difference and not the backward. And for images with different directions, how can I change this code to calculate finite difference derivative approximation matrix.

```
Df = sparse(-eye(N)+diag(ones(N-1,1),1)); Df(end,end)=0; % forward diff.
Db = sparse(eye(N)-diag(ones(N-1,1),-1)); Db(1,1)=0; % backward diff.
Dx = kron(Df,eye(N));                           % derivative in x-direction
if Th>=0
    Dy = kron(eye(N),Df);                       % derivative in y-direction
else
    Dy = kron(eye(N),Db);                       % derivative in y-direction
end
```

Comment: I don't think thats a cosntraint at all. You could use forward of backwards. I guess it depends what whoever wrote this code wants to do, but its not a mathematical limitation

Comment: @Ander Biguri Thanks for your comment. I need to make sure whether there is a relationship between the gradient orientation and the finite difference derivative approximation matrix.

Comment: Have you conisdered trying it?

Comment: @Ander Biguri  I have studied some articles to understand whether there is a relationship between these two structures. Now, I will try to do some numerical tests too. Thank you so much for your help.